# Mismatched parameters

Tags: javascript

I understand the case when a function may have less arguments than the function signature allows, such as:

```js
function sum(x, y=1) { return x+y; }
console.log(sum(5));
```

Or more parameters if its a vargs/rest function:

```js
function sum(...rest) {
    let s = 0;
    for (let n of rest) s += n;
    return s;
}
console.log(sum(1,2,3,4,5));
```

But why does the following not raise an error?

```js
'use strict';
function addEmUp() {
    let sum = 0;
    for (let arg of arguments) sum += arg;
    return sum;
}
console.log(addEmUp(1,2,3,4,5));
```

Comment: It's just how this language works. Always been like that.

Comment: Simply put, because that's the way javascript was designed. All functions can be passed an unlimited number of arguments, regardless of what you write in the argument list.

Comment: @NicholasTower I see -- do most people see that as an advantage or disadvantage of the language? Or just something that doesn't even matter.

Comment: It was the only way to work with a dynamic number of arguments before rest parameters arrived. Now that rest parameters are possible, it could theoretically be removed, but no-one wants to break existing code, so this will never happen.

Comment: Personally, i prefer languages with stronger type systems, so guess that means i'd call it a "disadvantage". But javascript was designed to be very flexible with its types, so this is an understandable outcome of that design decision. I mostly work in typescript these days, and typescript can give errors for missing or excess arguments.

Comment: Please revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default values for parameters and the rest parameters are a relatively new functionality of JavaScript, they were [introduced in ES2015](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions#function_parameters). Before that, the only way to have a function with any number of arguments was by using the [`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) object. It has been available since the first versions of JavaScript.

No matter how a function accesses its actual parameters, it can be called with less or more parameters than its declaration requires. When there are less actual values than declared parameters on the call, the remaining parameters are not initialized (their value is `undefined`), when the function is called with more values than it is declared, the extra values can be accessed only by using the `arguments` object (or with the *rest* syntax).